# '<' character is displaying as &amp;lt; in the soap response

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, websphere, soapui

I am using Java, Websphere/Jaxb/Jaxws for sending the SOAP response

The description property value is ' age is < 50' and is expected to display as below in soap response.

```
<description> age is < 50 </description>
```

But it is displayed like below

```
<description> age is &amp;lt; 50 </description>
```

in the soap response

After searching online Jaxb is doing escaping for few special characters like <,> etc and changing it.

Is there a way to inform jaxb not to do escaping at websphere server level or any other solution.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: It **should** display as `&lt;`. It **can't** (as in **must not**) display as `<`, and based on your output it looks like it's being double escaped.

Comment: so if the response is &lt; then is it the consumer who consumes should take care of convering &lt; to < ? Thanks